# How can a view page work with multiple word term name

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have user views page with path /members/%. 
(url as members/term-name).It shows if I use CONTEXTUAL FILTERS with term id but I need url with term name.
 Anyway , go back to story:
academician,math, math teacher, math students are terms.
It shows all members if path is members/math  or members/academician. 
No problem with one word term name.
But it doesn't show any member if url is members/math-teacher or members/math-student.
So it works with math terms but not with math teacher.
What am I missing ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you change the route in some way? The term id is still in the URL behind any alias you made (with Pathauto). If not, term id will always pull the value.

Comment: Yes pathauto is enable and taxonomy pattern  as [term:vocabulary]/[term:name] . Does it effect views ? Sorry if something misunderstood. View works with term id. I add this info to show main view structure is ok. But I need structure with term-name contextual filter.
 math-teacher's term id is 883

Scenario 1:If I build structure with term id (as domain.com/members/883). I see all math teacher. 
Scenario 2: No result  if I build views structure with term name (as domain.com/members/math-teacher)

Comment: Scenario 3: I see all math teachers if I change term name math teacher to math as one word.(as domain.com/members/math)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views, the multi-word term is a well-known active issue

- [issue #1027458: Allow to use multiple arguments with spaces](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1027458)
- [issue #1940206: term name contextual filter separator](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1940206)
- [issue #1977854: Transform dashes to spaces does not work still a problem](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1977854)

**Solution 1:**
You can use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to set up automatic aliases for your taxonomy terms.
**Solution 2:**
From views:

- Choose "Specify validation criteria" in settings of `Taxonomy Term` Contextual filter.
- Then Choose `Taxonomy Term` in **Validator** field.
- Choose your **Vocabulary**.
- Choose `Term name converted to term ID` in `Filter Value Type` Field. 
  *Please see attached screenshots for solution 2:*

  ---

  [image: screenshot one]
  [image: screenshot two]

  ---

  **Solution 3:**
  In views, you can create path aliases for term IDs by using [view_alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_alias) module.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but could TVI module solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks johirpro,
Patch at your first link worked for me with my settings(below). Many many thanks

Contextual Filters(with relationship)
Provide default value-Term id from URL
Specify validation criteria-Basic Validation+Show Page not found.